# INNER JOIN in DQL in Doctrine 2 / Zend Framework 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, dql, doctrine-query

I have an issue with DQL in Doctrine 2.

Subqueries seem to be unavailable in DQL, so I don't know how to transform :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID_DOMAINE, L_DOMAINE, b.ID_SS_DOMAINE, L_SS_DOMAINE, c.ID_COMPETENCE,     L_COMPETENCE
    FROM ((qfq_prod.REF_DOMAINE a inner join qfq_prod.REF_SS_DOMAINE b on a.id_domaine = b.id_domaine)
inner join qfq_prod.REF_COMPETENCE c on b.id_ss_domaine = c.id_ss_domaine)
inner join qfq_prod.REF_PERS_COMP d on c.id_competence = d.id_competence
```

into a DQL expression.

I tried it and got

> "Error: Class '(' is not defined."

I saw that we can use Query Builder to do this as well.

Being new with Doctrine 2, can someone explain to me how I can do this please ?

My DQL is currently :

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery ( "SELECT DISTINCT a.ID_DOMAINE, L_DOMAINE, b.ID_SS_DOMAINE, L_SS_DOMAINE, c.ID_COMPETENCE, L_COMPETENCE
FROM ((BdDoctrine\Entity\Domaine a inner join BdDoctrine\Entity\SsDomaine b on a.id_domaine = b.id_domaine)
inner join BdDoctrine\Entity\Competence c on b.id_ss_domaine = c.id_ss_domaine)
inner join BdDoctrine\Entity\LienPersComp d on c.id_competence = d.id_competence" );

$res = $query->getResult ();
```

Comment: The `'('` to which `'('` does it relate to? I can see there are two `'('` inside your query. Have you tried to reduce your query first (simplify it) to get it to run and then extend it step-by-step?

Comment: I searched an answer on the net and it seems like "(" aren't available in DQL. So I'm trying to find a way to do this without "(". This expression is working in SQL.
Full error is : `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 109 near '((BdDoctrine\Entity\Domaine': Error: Class '(' is not defined.`

Comment: Please add your DQL to the question as well - even if non-working. this is most often very useful if you ask a question btw.

Comment: I added it in the question. Thanks for the piece of advice. I'll remember to do it.

Comment: Yes, from somebody not knowing your code (you have on your computer), the question must be clear in it's own. E.g. here, the error message must match something, but you didn't post it first, so I was referring to the wrong example query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Subqueries seem to be unavailable in DQL, so I don't know how to transform :

Actually, they are. Your code (no offence) is hardly readable so I will give you an example:

```
//controller
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("Your:Bundle:Category") ;
$results = $repo->findAllForSomePage() ;

// CategoryRepository.php
public function findAllForSomePage()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder("o")
        ->innerJoin("o.products", "p", "WITH", "p.price>:price")->addSelect("p")
            ->setParameter("price", 50)
        ->where("o.id IN (SELECT s1.id FROM Your:Bundle:Something s1 WHERE s1.col1=5)")
        ->getQuery()->getResult() ;
}
```

Here is presumed you have Category hasMany Products relation and that you defined CategoryRepository file. You should never create queries in controller.

This example will fetch Categories only if they have Products with price bigger than 50, AND the ID of categories are those fetched by fictional subquery. This 100% works.

You should apply the same logic on your requirement.

Also, you **should not** use `ON` statement when using joins, that is handled by doctrine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the relationships properly defined in your entities, then you can make your joins on those relationships. And as Zeljko mentioned, you don't need to specify the **ON** condition, as the entities should already know how they are related. You are joining *entities* not tables. (That's under the hood.)

I don't know what your entities look like, so I made a guess at the relationship names below, but it should give you the idea.

```
$dql = 
<<<DQL    
SELECT 
    DISTINCT a.ID_DOMAINE, b.L_DOMAINE, b.ID_SS_DOMAINE, b.L_SS_DOMAINE, c.ID_COMPETENCE, c.L_COMPETENCE
FROM 
    BdDoctrine\Entity\Domaine a 
    JOIN a.ss_domaine b
    JOIN b.competence c
    JOIN c.lien_pers_comp d
DQL;

$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);

$res = $query->getResult();
```